# Where does the data of postgresql container save ans, and also where the location of container is?

Tags: postgresql, redis, docker-compose, dockerfile, nameko

I'm using the nameko from GitHub https://github.com/nameko/nameko-examples
and I deploy this application on docker. Once I stop the container all the data lost and I also not able to find the location of the container. I want to store each database date on my local computer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mount storage for the postgres container.
https://github.com/nameko/nameko-examples/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

```
postgres:
    container_name: nameko-example-postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
        - "5433:5432" # Exposing Postgres on different port for convenience
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: "orders"
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
        POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
    restart: always
```

you can add columes to the above snippet by

```
  volumes:
    - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql
```